# Excel 2007 VBA - Use VLOOKUP to find value in different worksheet and store result in active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this group and VBA.

I have a worksheet 'T2', with a variable number of rows. Starting with row 3, I want to look up the item number found in column 'E' and search worksheet 'Support'. The item number can be found somewhere in column 'A' in 'Support'. I need to bring the value in column 'B' in Support (that relates to that item number) and store it in column 'A' in worksheet 'T2'. I then want to repeat this process for every row in 'T2' up to and including the last row.

Can anyone help please as I just can't get this to work at all.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the code you have so far with any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

For the Vlookup part, this should be what you need.

```
Sub with_some_name

Dim result As String

With Worksheets("T2")
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("e3"), Worksheets("support").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
Range("A3").Value = result
End With

end sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but it didn't work. This also gets the error '1004' treatment (as in the above).

Answer (score 0):

variant using Dictionary:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = Sheets("Support")
    Set w2 = Sheets("T2")

    i = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("A1:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

    i = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("E3:E" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, -4).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

variant using vlookup:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set w1 = Sheets("Support")
    Set w2 = Sheets("T2")

    i = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
    For Each oCell In w2.Range("E3:E" & i)
        oCell.Offset(, -4).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oCell.Value, w1.[A:B], 2, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

variant using find method:

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set w1 = Sheets("Support")
    Set w2 = Sheets("T2")

    i = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
    For Each oCell In w2.Range("E3:E" & i)
        oCell.Offset(, -4).Value = w1.Cells(w1.Columns(1).Find(oCell.Value).Row, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

output result

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I couldn't get this to work. Nothing is showing on sheet T2 after running any of these. On the second opiton (VLookup), I am getting Runtime Error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error. I got this a lot on my attempts.

Comment: @tommill please show sample of the your data as output result in my post to get clear understanding what the issue behind your comment